# How to get Internet Explorer 9 to log into the Event Viewer logs

Tags: internet-explorer-9, event-viewer

I'm trying to find a way to enable IE 9 to log events into the event viewer.  We have some clients reporting problems and we think IE crashes.  I'd like to be able to log this event.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Event Viewer and Create a custom View In that you need to select Source and under that you can select IEFRAME as a source.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to notice this. Thanks! :)